# how to use kafka acls?

Tags: apache-kafka, acl

My version of kafka is 0.9.0.1 and I have two brokers: 192.168.1.100, 192.168.1.101 which are using ssl to authenticate and encrypt.

I had a topic named test09 and client ip is 192.168.1.102

When i add an acl with the command line interface like this:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --deny-principal User:* --deny-host 192.168.1.102 --operation Read --topic test09
```

the consumer from 192.168.1.102 can still get data.

Can someone tell me how to use ACLs in kafka?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you have missed to add the below property in Server.properties

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

-- Adding this line would enable the ACL to work via SimpleAclAuthorizer. -- Kafka by default comes with the `kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer` defined by the parameter `authorizer.class.name`.

You can try the below setup which might give complete idea.

https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9